# Rails bundle deploy only a few gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

My rails applications run on a shared host. I don't have access to a commandline and can't run the bundle command. I can run a few pre-selected rake commands.

On my development machine, I've done `bundle install --deployment`, so that all my gems are in vendor/bundle.

Problem is, however, that my development machine is not compatible with my shared host (32/64 bits), so the native extension of the mysql2 gem doesn't work on the shared host. The shared host does have the mysql2 gem installed, though.

<strike>If I remove 'mysql2' from the Gemfile, I get this error: `!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'`</strike> (<= this was because I had the adapter set to mysql instead of mysql2 in database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(same for test/production)

If I keep `gem 'mysql2'` in my Gemfile, I get this error (which makes sense, because of the native extension was compiled on a different machine:

`/home/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 - /home/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so`

If I remove `gem 'mysql2'`, I get:

`Please install the mysql2 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter)`

I would like to specify which gems should be loaded from my own applications vendor/bundle directory and which gems from the system gem directory.

1. Is this possible with bundler?
2. What's the best solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally it seems like you should consider switching hosts.

Comment: How would that solve the problem? It's still likely that my development machine uses a different architecture than the production machine. If I `bundle install --deployment`, it will still include my local native extension. Or should I run `bundle install --deployment` on the production machine?

Comment: Because then you would be be able to run `bundle install --deployment` on the production server as is intended.

Comment: Running bundler on the deployment machine solved the issue. My provider is now giving me access to the bundler command.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.yml file. Make sure you are not referring to the adapter that you don't have installed in your environment.

Comment: I did. I'm referring to mysql2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your gemlock file for -x86 gem references? I had a similar issue deploying from windows xp to 64-bit ubuntu. Modify these to remove the -x86 part and run bundle install again, this should build the 64-bit native gem if all the libraries are on the instance.